# Force a postback in Javascript for UpdatePanel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a function to close a modal:

```
function closeModal(name) {
    $(name).modal('hide');
}
```

But, my page also has an update panel and I need to trigger it.

I tried `__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '')` with no luck.

Thanks

The problem is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    createAutoClosingAlert('.success_alert', 6000);
    if(<%# IsAPostBack() %>){
        if(window.parent != null){
            window.parent.closeEditModal();
            window.parent.closeCalendarModal();
            window.parent.closeModal('#projectModal');
            window.parent.closeModal('#scheduleModal');
        }
    }
});
```

I call it from the parent so I cannot get the hidden ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to put a hidden button inside your update panel

```
<div style="display:none">
  <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
```

Then call the following in your script

```
document.getElementById('<%=Button2.ClientID%>').click();
```

The button click will cause a postback.

You can also look at [Page.GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.getpostbackeventreference%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: The problem is I call it from the parent so I cannot get the hidden ID.

Comment: Correct idea, but do not use button - but linkButton. (button is not accept the click for submit)

Comment: @Aristos I've just checked and I have this working with a Button, I would be interested to know what browser you're using?

Comment: @JackPettinger The button is render as input button, did not contain any javascript click code, the linkbutton contains. Now I do not know what you have test, but the javascript click that make full post back direct like pressing the button is not working on any browser. But if you are correct probably Milo select your answer.