# run postback for UpdatePanels

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a jquery modal that is being called from a button on my page. When the Webmethod for this button is called, and all logic is complete, I need to refresh several update panels on my page, to reflect the changes that took place in the WebMethod.

I've not used Update Panel much, but i've followed a view examples and am drawing a blank.

In the success portion of my call, i've placed this:

```
    success: function (msg) {
         $('#ApproveDialog').modal('hide');
         __doPostBack("<%= UpdatePanel1 %>","");
```

and my update panel is:

```
       <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" style="display:none;"/>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="grdMessageDate" runat="server"/>                </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="button" EventName="Click"/>
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I've left out part of the Grid, but i have a button in the first col, which is used to display further information.

When i click the button in the grid. this is causing the postback.

How do i call the postback in the success method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to postback in the success like so:

```
__doPostBack("UpdatePanel1","");
```

or if the updatepanel gets an asp.net formated id:

```
__doPostBack("<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>","");
```

Otherwise you could use the hidden button technique (I use this, but don't think it is the most elegant method)

see post: [Force a postback in Javascript for UpdatePanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928822/force-a-postback-in-javascript-for-updatepanel)

Comment: Hi Sanpopo, i agree it's not the most elegant way, but would appear to be the only option. I shall try, your suggestion. Do you know of any techniques of keeping the state? I mean apart from cookies

Comment: @CSharpNewBee It really depends on what you are trying to do, that is a huge topic and there are lots of flavors, viewstate, session state, application state, etc. If you have a question around a specific scenario, it might be best to post that in a seperate SO post. :)