# how to call the code behind function after page transition in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, .net, vb.net, jquery-mobile

on clicking the second li i.e My call status... the code behind function **GetCallDetails** is called. I want to call this function after transition to the page. the page **pagetwo** is a div in the same page.

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-display="push" data-theme="b">
        <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>
        <a href="#home" data-rel="close" class="ui-icon-delete">Close Menu</a>
        </li>

        <li data-icon="lock" data-ajax="false" rel="external">
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkBtnLogOut" class="navlink"></asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <div data-role="header">
      <a href="#mypanel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true"
                        data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="f" title="Menu"><span><span>
                            Menu</span><span>&nbsp;</span></span></a>
           <h1>My App</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
         <ul data-role="listview">
      <li>
        <a onclick="navigatepageone()" >
        <img id="img1" src="Images/Logacall.png" />
        <h2>Log A Call</h2>
        <p>Log A New Application or Hardware Related Call to IT HelpDesk</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a  href="#pagetwo" data-transition="slide" runat="server" onserverclick="GetCallDetails" >


      <img id="img3" src="Images/usercallstatus.gif"  />
        <h2>My Call Status</h2>
        <p>Get Your Call Status</p>
        </a>
      </li>


    </ul>
      </div>

      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h2>Footer</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Implement GetCallDetails as a PageMethod or in an asmx as a service web method. Then on page 2 show or create, make an AJAX call to the server.

Comment: But when i make ajax call the table repeater on my mage doesn;t get populated.

Comment: it was not clear from your code that you are using server controls. You could put the repeater in an update panel and trigger the update panel from javascript. Here is one way to trigger it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928822/force-a-postback-in-javascript-for-updatepanel